# How to open a new jsp page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following dropdown menu how can i redirect each menu to corresponding page by clicking each of menu? is it possible by using one javascript function if yes how?
thanks in advance...

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li id=home onclick="show(this.id)"><a href="home.jsp">Home</a></li>
  <li id=collection onclick="show(this.id)><a href="collection.jsp">Collection</a></li>
     <ul>
       <li id=men onclick="show(this.id)><a href="men.jsp">Men</a></li>
       <li id=women onclick="show(this.id)><a href="women.jsp">Women</a></li>
     </ul>
  <li id=contact onclick="show(this.id)><a href="contact.jsp">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Uh, doesn't an anchor tag do that already?

Comment: Please name your questions so that they describe the issue.  "java script getElementById" actually has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: The links are probably not working because you're missing some "closing" quotation marks for some of the onclick attributes.

Comment: @JamesMontagne if I dont use getElementById what should I use and how?

Comment: @Niko I just forgot it when I worte here..

Comment: Please validate your markup with http://validator.w3.org/. There are rules for html just like there are for java/jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need o JS function to redirect based on a parameter that, in your case, is the component ID, this will do the work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var show = function(id) {
        window.location.href = id + '.jsp';
    };
</script>
```

If you want to navigate DOM and get link's href attribute use:

```
document.getElementById(id).firstChild.href
```

Considering that the first element inside the component referred by ID is a link tag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Use `window.open("URL")` in your case URL is `this.id`

Also you can update `window.location`

read more here http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

Like Niko said you need closing quotes

```
.. onclick="window.open(this.id)" ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
$("div > ul li a").click(function() {
    window.location.href += "/" + $(this).parent()[0].id;
});
```

I tried to use a selector that didn't modify your HTML, so that's why it looks so icky.

Comment: The `a` tags don't actually have an `id`.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense.

I understand that your particular functional requirement is to invoke the link when the enduser clicks somewhere in the space of the `<li>` *outside* the link. To achieve that just set the CSS `display` property of the `<a>` element to `block`. This way the link will span the entire space of its parent element.

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="home.jsp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="collection.jsp">Collection</a></li>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="men.jsp">Men</a></li>
       <li><a href="women.jsp">Women</a></li>
     </ul>
  <li><a href="contact.jsp">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

with this CSS

```css
#menu li a {
    display: block;
}
```

No need for ugly JavaScript hacks. Opening a new JSP page location in the current window is by the way to performed by `window.location = 'some.jsp';`. But this is not necessary if you use the right solution for the concrete problem. In the future questions, try to elaborate more about the functional requirement instead of concentrating only on the solution of which you thought that it's the right solution for the particular functional requirement.